# Supercongruences for Bernoulli numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, congruences, bernoulli-numbers

> 1. $$ pB_{p-1}+(p-1)!(p-1) \equiv 0\mod p^2.$$
> 2. $$ pB_{p-1}-p-(p-1)!    \equiv 0\mod p^2.$$

I have (I believe) a proof for the above supercongruences, where $p$ is an odd prime, and  $B_{p-1}$ is a Bernoulli number. I guess it is already known, but I could not find a source, I have checked on Wikipedia only though.

The demonstration that I have found uses the follwing relationship, involving Binomial coefficients, Bernoulli and Stirling numbers of both kinds. 
 $$ \binom{n+1}{j}B_j=(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)\sum_{1\le k\le n+1}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \begin{Bmatrix}n+1\\k\end{Bmatrix}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}k \\ n+1-j \end{array}\right]$$
This is quite complicated and I would be interested in a more straigthforward proof.

EDIT

For $p=17,1733, 18433,?.. $,the congruence (1) holds modulo $p^3$.  I could not find that sequence in oeis.org, and I just added it.

For $p=103,839,2237,?.. $, the congruence (2) holds modulo $p^3$.  The sequence apparently is that of the [Lerch primes](https://oeis.org/A197632), but for the first one ($p=3$). Why is that?

These supercongruences sound like Wolstenholme's.

I also believe that each of the above supercongruence is a sufficient condition for $p$ to be odd prime. Please check.

Comment: Hmm, but $p B_{p-1}$ is not even an integer for odd primes $p$.

Comment: Actually the congruence (1) is easily obtained from (2) by adding $p+p!$ on the LHS, as $p+p! \equiv 0  \mod p^2  $  by Wilson theorem. And the general congruence reads $$pB_{p-1}+(p-1)!(kp-1) +(k-1)p \equiv 0\mod p^2. $$   for any integers $k$ positive, negative or zero.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering my own question: I just found [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.3113v5.pdf) paper, where another proof of (2) is given, along with the connection with Lerch primes when (2) holds modulo $p^3$